# Can I generate separate HTML file for each header using rmarkdown::render()?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I generate reports using `rmarkdown::render()` function on a list of .Rmd files and I get one HTML file for each of them.

That was fine until my dataset got bigger and my reports now contain >100 figures... The HTML files often end-up being >100MB and I now have some very big ones (~500MB).

The .Rmd is separated in several chunks so one might think I have to split my .Rmd in smaller files (let's say one chunk per file).
This is not (easily) doable because the .Rmd defines a data-processing workflow (figures generated in chunk3 require processings made in chunk1 and chunk2).

I would like to know if it is possible to split the rendering in several HTML files automatically.
Ideally I dream about a 'splitHeader' argument in `render()` that would generate separate HTML file for each header of a specified level.

I guess an ugly solution is to manually add conditional statements for every chunk/header that I would like rendered (or not), and call `render()` several time with different arguments. But this is extremely inefficient (and ugly, I said that already)...

Would somebody have suggestions to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this solve (or at least help to solve): You can have multiple independent .Rmd files (childs) dividing the content as you like. In a "Mother" file, you can add the child using:

````
```{r child = "yourChild.Rmd"}
```
````

The child .Rmd files should no contain any header information. That is, delete the first lines in you .Rmd that are something like:

```
---
title: "Your Title"
author: "Your name"
output: html_notebook
---
```

Comment: Is this goig to generate separate HTML files (one per child) ?  
I thought child documents were designed to be merged as a single output by 'mother'.

Comment: All HTML files get merged into the **mother** document. Are you getting a different result?

Comment: Yes that's what I get, unfortunately that is not what I would like to achieve.
I am trying to automatically split my master document in several sub-documents because the master one is too big.

Comment: In that case may be you can split your document by tabs. All you have to do is add { .tabset} after a heading and all the subheadings will automatically become tabs. The tab system broke when you add a header equal or superior to your initial heading. See [this](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#tabbed-sections)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that will help to make the document lighter.  
I end up with very large files and I am looking for a way to automatically split them in several 'sub-documents'.